# Grant Server roles SQL server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server

I have a tool which updates my sql table 'eptrack' with the following information

Server, Instance, userid, access, startdate and expirydate.

every time this table is updated a trigger will initiate a job which in turn connects to the respective server/Instance and grant the requested server roles.

I am able to grant the role via the following query.

```
exec sp_addsrvrolemember'na\admin_Test1', 'sysadmin'
```

However when i try to pick this info from the table via the below query,I get an error.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember '(select userid from eptrack)' , '(select access from eptrack)'
```

Could I get a help for a query on granting the server role picked from the table for the userid in the same table

Answer (score 0):

You should use a cursor for going through your table, get 1 row at a time, assign 2 variables and pass them to `sp_addsrvrolemember` like this:

```
declare @eptrack table (userid sysname, access sysname);
 insert into @eptrack values ('na\admin_Test1', 'sysadmin');

 declare  @rolename sysname,  @membername sysname; 

 select @rolename = access, @membername = userid
 from @eptrack;

 exec sp_addsrvrolemember @membername, @rolename;
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. I am seeing a new error this time.
"Cannot alter the server role 'na\admin_Test1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission".

I have sysadmin access for my login.

Comment: @Arvind Aryans, Sorry, it was an error in my code, I used userid for `@rolename`, not for `@membername`, I updated my answer

Comment: I fixed the issue. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

According to `sp_addrolemember`,this accepts variables as well

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  

sp_addrolemember [ @rolename = ] 'role',  
    [ @membername = ] 'security_account'
```

so you can try something like below

```
declare @rolename sysname,
       @membername sysname

       select @rolename='db_Datareader',@membername='test'
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename,@membername
```

The above select can be from your table,if there are multiple results from select this will not work as expected, you may want to have a method which tracks/get only one row at a time

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the assistance. I tried the above query as mentioned below

declare @rolename sysname,
       @membername sysname

select @rolename=(select access from eptrack),@membername= (select userid from eptrack)
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename,@membername

I see an error the user id does not exist. I just inserted the information in the table and executed the query after that.

Comment: I fixed the issue. Thank you for all the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, thank you. however we are entering the userid and access manually and we need those info picked from the table

declare @eptrack table (userid sysname, access sysname);

insert into @eptrack values ((select userid from eptrack), (select access from eptrack));

declare  @rolename sysname,  @membername sysname;

select @rolename = access, @membername = userid
 from @eptrack;

exec sp_addsrvrolemember @membername, @rolename;

I tried the above one and see an error user id is not a valid login.
wanted to check if I am entering the select command right?

The table will have new rows inserted frequently and the query needs to pick the userid and access from the table every time a new value is inserted.